# Is there an equivalent for Delphi's "with" command in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I was wondering if there is a command in C# which I can use like `with command` in Delphi?

```
// like this :
with(textbox1)
{
   .text="some text as text of text box";
   .tag=1231;
}
```

// in Delphi

```
with edit1 do 
 begin
   text="some text as text of edit1";
   tag=1231;
 end;
```

Comment: any C# basic tutorial should have the basic keywords and how to use them...

Comment: As other answers have rightly pointed out this construct does not exist in C#, however it does exist in Visual Basic .NET

Comment: @Matt Even better is that the VB equivalent has a syntax that solves most of the problems with Pascal's `with`.

Comment: The Delphi's with statement is IMHO potentially very dangerous. I've recently spent almost whole day catching an error caused by with. I was constructing a custom control object and wanted to assign it a OnContextPopup handler in the form's FormCreate handler. But in the declaration of the control class I forgot to mark the property as published. The code compiled and seemed correct, but the OnContextPopup property belonged to the form. Very nasty thing to track. So I've decided not to use the structure anymore and I think Hejlsberg knew why he hasn't included it into C#.

Comment: @Ladivlav: if Heljsberg implemented it like VB, it would be perfect because VB's `with` have all the convenience of Delphi `with` without the problems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not for already created instances.

However, when you create a new instance you can do:

```
var textbox1 = 
   new Textbox
   {
       Text = "some text as text of text box",
       Tag = 1231
   };
```

Answer (score 13):

No, that does not exist in C#.

Comment: Well now, that is an unexpected bonus... :-)

Comment: Why? If it would be implemented, probably it will be like VB.NET's `with` which is **much** better than Delphi's one.

Answer (score 4):

No, it does not exist in C#, however, when *creating* an object, you can do like this:

```
var textbox1 = new TextBox {
    Text = "some text as text of text box";
    Tag = 1231
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been 11 years.

C# has added the records feature. You can use the `with` keyword with c# records.

Since records are immutable it instantiates and returns a new object when you use `with`.

```
public record FullName(string FirstName
                     , string LastName);

var name = new FullName("Jack", "Beyer");

var newName = name with { FisrtName = "Mohsen" };
```

Comment: Despite using the same keyword, these behave radically differently from each other.  The C# `with` statement is no a mean of referencing members of an object without repeating the identifier, it's a means of constructing a new object that differs from a provided object in specified ways.  Neither languages operator is capable of performing the actions of the other language's operator.

Answer (score -2):

There's something called [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but compared to Delphi/Pascal it's works more like try/finally.

Answer (score -2):

No but depending on what you are trying to do, the following would work:

```
TextBox t = textbox1;

t.text="some text as text of text box";
t.tag=1231;
```